# specify a temporary document instead of initial source document for a template rule

Tags: xslt-3.0

The match attribute of `<xsl:template>` defines which nodes this
template rule applies to. I think, the matched nodes are implicit coming from initial source document.

For example, here is a part of my XSLT template:

```
<xsl:mode name="unroll" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="StructFormat[@repeat]" mode="unroll">
   ...
</xsl:template>
<xsl:variable name="complete-struct">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="unroll"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

This template processes the intial source ducument, and the result is saved in a variable. How can I let this template rule apply to a temporary document loaded by `document()` function? I tried like this and it didn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="/" mode="unroll">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('a.xml')/*"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="unroll">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part with the global variable

```
<xsl:variable name="complete-struct">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="unroll"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

builds a variable processing the child nodes of the global context item (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-global-context-item)

you can change that to

```
<xsl:variable name="complete-struct">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc('a.xml')/node()" mode="unroll"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

to process nodes from another document or if you run your XSLT processor with its API check where/how you could set that global context item to your particular document if needed/wanted (see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#setGlobalContextItem-net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmItem- for Saxon 9.9).

I think your attempt adding

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="unroll">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

is wrong, your initial code has a declaration `<xsl:mode name="unroll" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` which should do fine and if you wanted to spell it out you would need

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="unroll">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. This is exactly what I need. So the key point is use `select` attribute to select those nodes when trigger a template rule.